# How to remove the quiz maker text

Tags: html

I have a html snippet, when i upload that to my website i see a small text called quiz maker, when i try to remove it, the snippet fails, so how do i remove the Quiz maker text and link, while making the snippet functional?

```html
<div><a quiz="Q39I85" href="http://www.poll-maker.com/QuizMaker">Quiz Maker</a></div><script src="//cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js" async language="javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style` attribute to set `display` property as `none`. This will hide the link but the script will find it and your code will not break. Have a look at the working snippet below.

```html
<div><a quiz="Q39I85" href="http://www.poll-maker.com/QuizMaker" style="display:none;">Quiz Maker</a></div><script src="//cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js" async language="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If it worked for you, then please consider choosing it as an answer for future viewers of this question.